# What does 'OLS estimator for $\sigma^2$' mean?

Tags: regression

In the Wikipedia article on OLS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), it mentions that $S^2$ is the 'OLS estimator' for $\sigma^2$. I have no idea what this means. Does this notion of OLS have anything to do with OLS in the sense of having minimal error sum of squares?

Comment: I did not see it in the article, you might want to show the quote you mean in more detail for context. I suspect they mean that this is the estimate based on the sample for the unknown population parameter.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I'm new here, should have thought to clarify the section I was talking about. The first answer below quotes it.

Answer (score 2):

That is a long page.  Your quotation comes from [about halfway down the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Finite_sample_properties)

This is the the result of trying to minimise the sum of squares of the residuals $y_i-\hat y _i$ from linear regression as you are presumably familiar with. The relevant definition of $s^2$ is [higher up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation) where it says

> $s^2 = \frac{\hat\varepsilon ^\mathrm{T} \hat\varepsilon}{n-p} = \frac{(My)^\mathrm{T} My}{n-p} = \frac{y^\mathrm{T} M^\mathrm{T}My}{n-p}= \frac{y ^\mathrm{T} My}{n-p} = \frac{S(\hat\beta)}{n-p},\qquad
>     \hat\sigma^2 = \frac{n-p}{n}\;s^2 $
>
> The denominator, $n−p$, is the statistical degrees of freedom. The first quantity, $s^2$, is the OLS estimate for $σ^2$, whereas the second, $\hat\sigma^2$, is the MLE estimate for $\sigma^2$.

Rather than using matrices and vectors, you could say $s^2=\frac1{n-p}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y-\hat y_i)^2$ and if you were doing simple linear regression, i.e. with $p=1$ regressor or independent variable, you would have $s^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y-\hat y_i)^2$, which may look more familiar.  This is the unbiased estimator of the variance of the error term $\varepsilon_i$ in your model.

Comment: Did you actually answer the question "Does this notion of OLS have anything to do with OLS in the sense of having minimal error sum of squares"?

Comment: @AJKOER I think so.  I started with "*This is the the result of trying to minimise the sum of squares of the residuals $y_i-\hat y _i$ from linear regression as you are presumably familiar with."*  I accept it is also about unbiasedness and have inserted that towards the end

Comment: Arguably so, at least for someone who has already mastered the material. Perhaps, user Othi will comment.

Comment: What I don't understand is why this quantity would be an estimator of the variance of the error term. You could prove this using Lehman-Scheffé, but why is it the case according to the OLS method? I'm guessing it has something to do intuitively with the fact that $s^2$ is a kind of sample variance of your error terms, but then I don't see why you don't divide by n-1.

Comment: @othi the reason you often divide by $n-1$ in calculating the variance is that the estimates of other parameters biases down the residual estimates you are interested in.  In OLS regression with multiple independent variables (i.e. parameters) this happens to an even greater extent, so to unbias the estimate you need to divide by an even smaller number, here $(n-p)$

Comment: So $s^2$ IS a kind of sample variance? Using the values of the error terms and the fact that their expectation is $0$?

Comment: @othi is an unbiased estimator for the variance of the error term, similar to the sample variance being so-called because it is an unbiased estimator of the population variance

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question, consider the matrix formula for the Generalized Least-Squares case as indicated by Equation [4-15] in [this educational reference](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/MathStat/GreeneChapter4.pdf), for example, to quote:

${Var[b | X] = σ^{2}(X’X)^{-1}}$

Now, if we consider the degenerate case of just one regression coefficient, the OLS variance estimate of this parameter (namely, the sample mean) becomes simply:

${Var[\mu | X] = σ{^2}/n}$

However, the suggested sample variance above is the uncorrected sample variance (where the correction factor is known as Bessel's correction).

As a supporting source, see [discussion here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#:%7E:text=The%20sample%20mean%2C%20on%20the,of%20the%20population%20mean%20%CE%BC.&text=%2C%20and%20this%20is%20an%20unbiased%20estimator%20of%20the%20population%20variance.&text=The%20ratio%20between%20the%20biased,is%20known%20as%20Bessel%27s%20correction), to quote:

> The reason that an uncorrected sample variance, ${S^2}$, is biased stems from the fact that the sample mean is an ordinary least squares (OLS) estimator for μ: ${\overline {X}}$...

So, it does NOT actually have anything to do with OLS regression parameters themselves (in the degenerate case discussed, the unbiased sample mean, which produces the lowest value for the sum of squares) "in the sense of having minimal error sum of squares", as you asked.